# Can local rotations lead to a gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, rotation, klein-gordon-equation, poincare-symmetry

I  was reading about the relation between electromagnetism and the complex Klein-Gordon field. The KG field had a global $U(1)$ symmetry and upon demanding that even a local phase transformation must leave the Lagrangian invariant, it was necessary to introduce the covariant derivative along with the gauge field $A_{\mu}$. Then after writing down a Lagrangian for the gauge field, we 'discover' electromagnetism. However, the complex K.G. field also has a global Poincaré symmetry. The Lagrangian remains invariant when $\phi$ (which transforms trivially under the action of the Poincaré group) is rotated or boosted by an element of the trivial representation of the Poincaré group. So what will happen if one demands that the Lagrangian for the complex K.G. field (or for something more non trivial, the Dirac field) should be invariant even under local rotations? Upon following the procedure that was used to end up at the gauge fields in the $U(1)$ case, is it possible to get some sort of 'new' gauge field corresponding to rotations, boosts and translations?

Comment: Invariance under local Lorentz transform is known as local tetrad rotations, which is the gauge group of gravity.

Comment: But what about local translations?

Comment: The rough equivalence that I have usually seen is that local Lorentz invariance gives rise to general relativity while the local Poincaré invariance gives rise to the Einstein-Cartan theory, of general relativity with torsion.